# cannot download any apps from store in Nokia lumia 630?

Tags: store, windows-10-mobile, app-update

I cannot download any app from store.Please help me.When I click on install it is not showing any message.My internet connection is fine.

Comment: If you go to Downloads and Updates does it show up there?

Answer (score 1):

Please try going under **`Settings > email + accounts`** and make sure that you have signed in with your Microsoft Account. If it prompts you to input your microsoft account password, please do.
Once that is done, try restarting your phone and then accessing the store again, and downloading applications.

Answer (score 1):

Try soft resetting your phone.

Press volume down key + Power key for around 15-20 seconds.

After leaving the keys, your phone should restart automatically.

Try re-installing apps which were not installed before.

Also, check your regional settings that whether the app is available for your region or not.

Hope it helps!